# Sorting a parent object by value of its set child

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to sort list of parent object by the value of its child which is 
a set. So let's say I have the ff:

Parent1 with children name rose
Parent2 with children name cameo
Parent3 with children name of abba, zeon, max.

When I sort it descending it should show Parent3 first since it has a z. 
This is my current hql which gets a wrong result of 1>2>3:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Parent p JOIN p.children c ORDER BY c.name desc
```

Without a distinct, it gets it just fine although it selects multiple same parents.

I have a model setup like below:

```
 public class Parent {
 private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<Child>();
 }

 public class Child{
  private String name;

 }
```

Edit: Managed to sort it [HQL order by within a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666423/hql-order-by-within-a-collection) although when both parents have the same children.name value, it doesn't compare the next possible value. I.e.

If Parent1 has children abba, zeon
Parent2 has children abba, cameo
Ascending order should prioritize Parent2 first.

Comment: Looks like this was already answered in [hql-order-by-within-a-collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666423/hql-order-by-within-a-collection) Hope this helps

Comment: @Jorge Thank you this works although if both parents have the same children.name value it doesnt compare the next name value i.e both have a child named acacia assuming ascending order it will compare the next value until it finds the possible earliest value if there are any

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want duplication of the parent you can't do it with a collection. What you can do is to select the Parent and subselect the the max element (alphabeticaly) in each Parent and order by it.

Something around these lines.

```
select p from Parent p 
where p.maxChild = 
     (select max(c.name) from Child c where c.parentID=p.parentID)
```

You can use @Formula to map the max element if you want to. So it is not realy nessesary to use a collection at all.

Actualy it may be even better with formula, you can map the maximum name and order by it directly without fetching the collection at all.